# Restrict image access by URL

Tags: image, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, hide

I have an image file on my website and I don't want people to directly access this file by URL, so they have to go on my website to view it. e.g.:

> www.test.com/wp-content/sample.jpg

I found a way to restrict direct access to **ALL images**, but I just intend to protect **one file**.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg)$ - [F]
```

I really don't know how to edit the code to only protect this single file.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you can add rewrite rule for single or several images in the following way:

```
RewriteRule ^wb-content/sample.jpg$ - [F]
RewriteRule ^wb-content/(sample1.jpg|sample2.jpg)$ - [F]
```